# Function signature : C++ Templates complete guide

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading book "template compelte guide" , I section : **12.2.1 Signatures** I couldn't understand a sentence of author :

> Its return type, if the function is generated from a function template

what does the author means by "function generated by function template" ? , is he talking about template-id here? if so, why does return type matters in the case, since signature is defined by us?

A trivial example will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: A more complete quote to those not having the book handy (or memorized) could be helpful to understand what the authors are talking of in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In section 12.2.1 the authors describe under which situations declarations of functions can coexist. The declaration of function templates can coexist even if they have a different return type, e.g., you can declare:

```
template <typename T> int  f();
tepmlate <typename T> char f();
```

If you make these functions non-templates, you can't even declare them. Of course, in the form above you won't be able to call the function although you may be able to explicitly the select one of the functions using a cast (I'm not sure about this).

The primary use of having functions with different return types coexist (although this wasn't the original intent), is to remove some of these functions from the overload set based on condition, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized, T>::type
f(T); // used for types for which std::numeric_limits<T> is specialied

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized, T>::type
f(T); // used for types for which std::numeric_limits<T> is not specialied
```

Comment: I don't think a cast can work. The problem is that `T` cannot be provided : `f<T>` is ambiguous. If T was a deduced parameter of both templates (i.e. `int f<T>(T)`) then `int (*p)(double) = &f` would work, even without cast. In the overload set `f`, there's only one function with that precise type.

Comment: I appreciate your reply to worst question ever (This Q is more of language(verbal) issue to me) but I am still wondering why would author write and what he means by  `function generated by function template` rather than simply writing `return type of function template` ?

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: A function template isn't a function but in this section the authors want to describe the interactions of the overload set which is operates on actual functions rather than function templates. To get a function from a function template you'd need to "generate" it. I think, normally the term *instantiate* is used but I don't know why the authors didn't use this term.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks a lot, your's comment cleared everything. I love ya :)

Comment: @MSalters: When the function template is used in a suitable context, i.e., when casting it to a function pointer type, initializing a function pointer type, or when passing it to a function taking a function pointer type the expression `f<double>` correctly deduces the correct template [(I just tried it)](http://ideone.com/pfBZsG). Of course, calling `f<double>()` directly is ambiguous.